# Django Multiple Project login clash

Tags: django

I have multiple django projects. Say:

- Project_1
- Project_2

These 2  projects are running simultaneously on development server in different terminals. Both have different secret keys and both are using separate sqlite database for authentication.

First I login to Project_1 and it works fine but when I log in to Project_2, I am logged out of Project_1 automatically. I can't figure out why is this happening.

Both are inside different virtual environments. How am i not able to log into both projects simultaneously. I am using ubuntu 14.04.

I tried to switch database to Postgresql for Project_1 but same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using two browsers or using a private (incognito) window.

If you don't want to use two different browsers to browse through the project,
You can use http://127.0.0.1:XXXX/ for `PROJECT_1` and http://localhost:XXXX/ for `PROJECT_2`.

Comment: That worked for my localhost.. but what if i am using a server with an ip address like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. There i cant use localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: You can change your hosts file to make an entry for `sitethatdoesntexists.com` which points to the ip address, then you can use ip address for one project and the fake host for the other one.

Answer (score 0):

The browser assigns the cookie to the domain, 127.0.0.1. So even if you run one on 127.0.0.1:8000, and second on 127.0.0.1:9000, they will both use the same authentication cookie.

A simple solution would be to use another browser, e.g. project1 on Firefox, and project 2 on Chrome

Comment: I am running both on different ports 8000 and 9000